# How can I use \textalpha in a section or subsection?

Tags: subscripts, section-titles, texpad, alphabeta

I can use `\textalpha` in the title like this

```
\title{Tool\textsubscript{\textalpha} other text}
```

> Output : Toolα

and it is working fine.

But if I use the `\textalpha` in section, for example

```
\section{Tool\textsubscript{\textalpha}}
```

it replaces 'α' with a 'A'.

> Output: ToolA

Distribution - MacTeX

Engine - pdfLaTeX

Full Example :

```
\documentclass[sigconf, review]{acmart}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\begin{document}

\title{Tool\textsubscript{\textalpha}: Other Text}



\begin{abstract}
ToDo
\end{abstract}



\keywords{kyword}

\maketitle

\section{Tool\textsubscript{\textalpha}}

ToDo


\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy to see if they can replicate. Additionally also add which engine (pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex) you are using and which latex distribution

Comment: Are your section titles in upper case (or small caps)?

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: @user240002 Upper Case. Thanks.

Comment: I ask again please provide a full minimal example others can copy and test! You list no document class or preamble so we have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Well, then you may want to use `\MakeLowercase` on `\textalpha`, possibly with some `\protect`s. Try `\section{Tool\textsubscript{\MakeLowercase\textalpha}}`.

Comment: @daleif Thanks again. Added the full example.

Comment: If as you say (I will not be at a pc for another hour) the titles are in Upper case, then the output is correct as A is an upper case alpha. Depending on how acmart made their sections  upper case there are counter measures.

Comment: Unrelated, everything after `\end{document} ` is ignored so thst endinput is never seen

Comment: Use `\section{Tool\textsubscript{\texorpdfstring{\MakeLowercase\textalpha}{a}}}`.

Comment: @user240002. Thank you so much. This is working fine.

Comment: Another solution would be to load the `textcase` package as `amsart` which `acmart` is build on top of is using `\MakeTextUppercase` if present, and `textcase` has `\NoChangeCase{\textalpha}`. though you still need `\texorpdfstring` for hyperref as can be seen from the log.